# Automate validation in Yii (special case)

Tags: php, yii

Is there a way to automate validation in Yii if the fields of a model are rows in a table instead of columns? The form is generated at runtime and there is a table just for the elements of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your *model*, you can define has many *properties* as you wish.
By doing that, you can then call those *properties* on your `rules()` *model* *method*.

Something like:

```
public $myproperty;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
         array('myproperty', 'required', 'message'=>'This field is REALLY required')
    ),
```

Then, on your *view* if, for example, you use *CActiveForm*, you can:

```
$form->error($yourModelNameHere, 'myproperty');
```